# Select min value from another table with other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables; the first table is for the names of the main halls. It is called the halls.

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TA |
| 2 | TB |

The second table is for indoor halls, named `Halls_Interior`, for each main hall, and contains the name of the inner hall, the starting date of the price period, its end date, and the price of the period.

| id | IdHalls | Name | FromDate | EndDate | Price | (comment) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | price1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | 500 |  |
| 2 | 1 | price2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 | 200 | **this is min price** |
| 3 | 2 | price3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-01 | 80 |  |
| 4 | 2 | price4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-01 | 50 | **this is min price** |

What is required is to display all the main halls from the first table and put a field with the name of the smallest price, the date of the beginning and the date of the end of the period, so that the form of the query becomes as follows:

| NameHalls | NameHallsInterior | PriceName | FromDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TA | price2 | 200 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-01 |
| TB | price4 | 50 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-12-01 |

As you can see, only two halls appeared, and each hall has the details of the lowest price found, meaning that I just want the lowest price data and put it next to each hall.

Here is the query that I reached, but unfortunately it will show all the internal halls, and I only want data on the lowest price for each main hall

```
SELECT 
    HallsInterior.NameHalls, HallsInterior.NameHallsInterior,  
    HallsInterior.FromDate, HallsInterior.EndDate, HallsInterior.Price
FROM     
    Halls 
INNER JOIN
    DataHall ON Halls.Id = DataHall.HallId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also achieve this using OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT a.Name,
    b.PriceName,
    b.FromDate,
    b.EndDate,
    b.Price
FROM Halls a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 x.IdHalls,
        x.[Name] as PriceName,
        x.FromDate,
        x.EndDate,
        x.Price 
    FROM Halls_Interior x
    WHERE x.IdHalls = a.Id
    ORDER BY x.Price
) b
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, the query was much clearer for your solution you put forward

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT H.Name, D.PriceName, D.FromDate, D.EndDate, D.Price
FROM     Halls H INNER JOIN
(SELECT IdHalls, Name as PriceName, FromDate, EndDate, Price, 
ROW_NUM() OVER(PARTITION BY IdHalls ORDER BY PRICE) as nr 
FROM Halls_Interior ) D ON H.Id = D.IdHalls
where D.nr = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, and for the most wonderful solution, but is the query with use
ROW_NUMBER()
will be slow?

Comment: @EBRAHEM Not necessarily. Depends on the cardinality of the results vs the whole table. Eg small percent of the joined table then `OUTER APPLY` will be faster, large percent or if it's not well-indexed then `ROW_NUMBER` will be faster,